# downgrade Expo Go in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a working app in React Native. I run it on the Android Studio emulator with Expo Go. A few days ago I got a warning that I had to upgrade Expo SDK from version 45 to 47/48/49 and if i didn't, the Expo Go app would not be compatible anymore (see picture below). The upgrade to version 47 went fine and the app is still running in the emulator and compiling with eas build.

Upgrading Expo SDK any further isn't possible.

Now my question is: can I somehow downgrade the Expo Go app so that I can still run the app in the emulator in the future?

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend considering a downgrade. Instead, it's advisable to maintain complete backups of your entire project and upgrade step by step(version by version).